# Store User Settings in Parse Cloud

Tags: parse-platform

What is the recommended way to store user settings in Parse Cloud?

I've two approaches of which I don't know which one is best suitable for a scalable app or if there is a better way of doing this.

The first approach is to create a class with all settings for each user and have a relation between the user and the setting.

The other approach is to simply store the settings for each user in a user object. I feel the second approach is the better one.

I've had a look at `PFInstallation` but not entirely sure if that can be used to set User Settings or if the use case is for push notifications only.

Comment: You might be better off asking this in Parse forums too, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers

Comment: PFInstallation is for storing data needed to target push notifications  so you probably would not want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your solutions:

1. an associated class to hold user settings
2. store attributes directly in the user class

Are valid.

The advantage of #1 is that it will be easier to secure the settings. In the case of #1, you can create an [ACL](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.ACL.html) when you create each user's setting object that will allow only the user associated with that record to read, edit or delete the settings object.

In the case of #2, if any of the fields are sensitive, then you'll need to explicitly protect those fields using the `userSensitiveFields` [config key](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/ca286b7108197034a3ff02063a259ff12181a329/src/defaults.js#L35) to ensure that they are not returned when user records are queried.